# Best way to find the 2 closest vertices from a list of vertices?

Tags: python, vertices

Assuming there is an object, then a list of vertices that could be.

```
obj = bpy.context.object
for v in obj.data.vertices:
    #?print(closest vertex/vertices)###noob example
```

for example , how to find the closest vertices of v[0]?

is there any bmesh operator? or something really fast?

Comment: You could have a look at Blender's internal [KDTree](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/mathutils.kdtree.html) implementation.

Comment: Thanks this is very useful, but I'm still groping in the dark because I don't know how to approach, this example refers to some points, while I would like to refer to a list of vertices, and at the same time find the vertex closest to the one processed in that moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naively, this creates a look-up list of closest vertex indices.

```
import mathutils
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.object

# create a kd-tree from a mesh
me = ob.data
size = len(me.vertices)
kd = mathutils.kdtree.KDTree(size)
for i, v in enumerate(me.vertices):
    kd.insert(v.co, i)
kd.balance()

# create ordered list of closest vertex indices
closest_vIdx = []
for v in me.vertices:
    co_find = v.co
    closest_2 = kd.find_n(co_find,2)
    closest_vIdx.append(closest_2[1][1])

#Insert the index of the queried vertex here:
vIdx = 5707

print (f"vertex:{vIdx} closest vertex:{closest_vIdx[vIdx]}")
```

Bear in mind with this one:

- The distances are in 3-space, not necessarily down edges.
- Only the 'first' of any set of equidistant vertices is chosen

You wouldn't want to build the KDTree (or the closest list) more often than necessary - the best way of finding the closest vertex may depend on exactly if/when you want to modify the mesh, and would therefore have to rebuild the tree.

Comment: Yes, that is kd.find_n is the right function! Ty

Comment: What if i want to find the closest vertex in another object mesh, how to adapt the code ?

Comment: @WadeWang  The closest vertex in the target mesh to _any_ vertex in the source mesh, or the closest to a _particular vertex_ in the source mesh? (This may be worth posting as another question, having made that clear.. there are better scripters than me out there)