# Select an object from its location with Python

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to select one object among more than 8,000 objects from location.

I have a CSV data which determines each object(plane) location.  After putting all planes, I need to move some vertices of each plane.
I have done creation, so next I would like to know how to select one plane and make it active from its location. The CSV file has number for (x,y,z).
Blender version is 2.8

Thank you.

Comment: you mean you want to give some position and find your objects based on that? if that's the case the best work is to use numpy.

Comment: If you give an example I could help more. (put your csv and tell precisely what you want to do)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156763/best-way-to-find-the-2-closest-vertices-from-a-list-of-vertices  Simply replace vert locations with object locations.